# Book about teenage boy who finds out he’s part alien, is good at gymnastics and helps with an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, books, alien-invasion

Early 2000s is when I read it. The book was about a teenage boy who turns out to be part alien (I think). He was really good at gymnastics his eyes did this crazy dilating thing that would freak out his friend and he had a motorcycle by the end of the book. An invasion occurs and he finds out he’s part alien.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! For some help improving this question, see [our incredible guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999).

Comment: Did the story take place entirely on earth, or was the character brought to Earth by the alien force as part of their 'diplomatic' group?   The one I'm thinking of has a character who thought he was human, but ended up being an alien surgically altered to appear human.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like ["Invasion America"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_America). David Carter, Earth teen, discovers he is the half alien son of an alien ruler that is on the run from a coup.  His human mom hid his father after he crashed landed on Earth, and they fell in love.    He was very good at gymnastics, and he also was given a a motorbike that was enhanced with alien technology so it could fly.  He also received a silver glove that was a weapon only usable by royalty, which gave him kind of telekinetic abilities.  It was actually a cartoon originally, but there was a novelization of it by Christie Golden in 1998.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be thinking of The Dark Side of Nowhere. Published by Neal Shusterman in 1997. The Protagonist is named Jason and he begins the story depressed over the recent death of his friend Ethan. Jason finds that Ethan is still alive but hiding because he is an alien who has lost his ability to maintain a human like form and goes on to find out that he, his family and many other people in his hometown are also aliens who were sent ahead of an invasion force.

The story uses the term "warrior fools" to refer to the aliens and "fragile people" to refer to the humans. The looming invasion that drives the plot is often referred to as the "ten thousand ships".

They also had gloves that functioned as energy weapons.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Side_of_Nowhere
978-0-316-78907-3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This may well be a correct and useful answer. Please add some details in support. For a start,  please name the author. And give a brief plot synopsis, showing some details that match the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first post. I have augmented it based on your suggestions.